# Why is my Bootstrap Sidebar overlapping my footer? Using stickynavbar.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

When there are a certain number of items in my Bootstrap sidebar the sidebar overlaps with the footer content. I cannot just change the footers top margin or give the sidebar a bottom margin. Neither of these resolves the overlap. Also, I am using stickyNavbar.js which may be what is causing the overlay issue. If so, would this be solved by determining when the sidebar is activated and adding a margin to the footer? How would I detect this and make this change with StickyNavbar.js? http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/

Here is an image of the resulting issue:

[image: Sidebar Overlap]

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="main-content" >
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="sidebar" class="hidden-xm" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
            <nav class="leftnav">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Jobs@IU</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Recruitment & Outreach</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">The Hiring Process</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Pre-posting steps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Posting process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Hiring proposals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Closing the posting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Temporary Hiring Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Student Employment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Related Resources</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">Employee Policies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/:introContent.asp">PeopleAdmin</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ajaxContent">
    <div ng-view> </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Sidebar CSS:

None, using default styles from bootstrap

Footer CSS:

```
   .footerspan{ background-color:#4b3b32; padding-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 50px; }
```

Comment: and how will anyone answer it without code example? Give your footer css styles and maybe sidebars..

Comment: @AndrewEvt Does this help?

Comment: i think your sidebar have css style position: absolute or fixed - and it creates this issue. Try to change it to relative...  and data-offset-top="100" - what is it for?